# Ghost Blog - Unable to upgrade from 3.4.2 to 4.2.0

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm, ghost-blog

I have followed the following to work on the Ghost Blog,
Github+Herok+Ghost > One click install, it installed the V3 ghost on the server. however i am unable to upgrade to latest version of ghost i.e. version 4.2.0

please can you guide me what i am missing.

Steps i have done so far as follows

a) Installation >  https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/snathjr/ghost-on-heroku
b) Local Copy >> saved on c drive >> C:\ghost-on-heroku screenshot below

[local copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agIMv.png)

i have run the following commands so far, and getting this error.

**CMD**

C:>heroku login
C:>cd ghost-on-heroku

C:\ghost-on-heroku>heroku git:clone -a **project name**
Cloning into 'project name'...
remote: Counting objects: 1727, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1091/1091), done.
remote: Total 1727 (delta 554), reused 1717 (delta 547) eceiving objects:  89% (1538/1727), 11.
Receiving objects: 100% (1727/1727), 11.59 MiB | 3.62 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (554/554), done.

C:\ghost-on-heroku>cd projectname

C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname>npm outdated
Package                       Current  Wanted  Latest  Location  Depended by
ghost                         MISSING  3.42.4   4.2.0  -         projectname
ghost-storage-adapter-s3      MISSING   2.8.0   2.8.0  -         projectname
ghost-storage-cloudinary      MISSING   2.1.5   2.1.5  -         projectname
ghost-webdav-storage-adapter  MISSING   0.3.5   0.4.1  -         projectname
mysql                         MISSING  2.18.1  2.18.1  -         projectname

C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname>ghost -v
Ghost-CLI version: 1.16.3

C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname>npm -v
7.8.0

C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname>node -v
v10.24.1

C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname>npm upgrade ghost

added 1328 packages, and audited 1763 packages in 48s

1 package is looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

20 vulnerabilities (5 low, 3 moderate, 12 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname>npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating ghost to 0.11.14,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating ghost-webdav-storage-adapter to 0.4.1,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN deprecated webdav@3.6.2: WebDAV 3.x is deprecated: Please upgrade to v4.
npm ERR! code 231
npm ERR! path C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname\node_modules\ghost
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node core/server/utils/npm/preinstall.js
npm ERR! ERROR: Unsupported version of Node
npm ERR! Ghost supports LTS Node versions: ^6.9.0
npm ERR! You are currently using version: 10.24.1
npm ERR! This check can be overridden, see https://docs.ghost.org/v0.11/docs/supported-node-versions for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-08T11_-debug.log

C:\ghost-on-heroku\projectname>

please help me what i would need to get the blog updated to ghost 4.2.0 (i have tried with installing multiple nodejs version, i.e. version 12, version 14 etc, but may be i am doing something wrong)

Comment: Check it here - https://forum.ghost.org/t/unable-to-upgrade-ghost-4-2/21687/4